# To give time complexity of function to find rank of (3x3) matrix

Tags: python, time-complexity, linear-algebra

**I did following calculations to find time complexity of 'rank' function
,'rank' is using onother functions such as 'minor', 'cofactor', 'det1', 'det2', 'det3' to complete the whole task**

```
 1. T(n) = t1 + t2
 2. t1(n) = O(n^2) + o(1) == O(N^2)
 3. t2(n) = n*n*O(n**2) == n^4
 4. T(n) = O(n^4)
```

**Also time complexities of onother functions are :-**

```
    1. minor = O(n^2)
    2. cofactor = O(n^2)
    3. det1,det2 = O(1)
    4. det3 = O(n^2)
```

**I am Not sure whether calculations are correct or not and whether complexity of 'minor'
will be considered or not**

```
  import copy

def minor(M, i, j):
        #T(n) = O(n^2)
        Mat = copy.deepcopy(M)
        Minor = [[Mat[x][y] for y in range(len(Mat[x])) if y != j] for x in range(len(Mat)) if x != i]
        return Minor

def cofactor(M,i, j):
        #T(n) = O(n^2) as using minor function in line 1 of this function
        m = minor(M,i, j) 
        val = [[1,-1,1],[-1,1,-1],[1,-1,1]]
        c = val[i][j]
        if len(m) == 1:
            c *= det1(m)
            return c

        elif len(m) == 2:
            c *= det2(m)
        return c

def det1(M):
    #to find determinant of 1x1 matrix
    # T(n) = O(1)
    try:
        d = M[0][0]
        return d
    except Exception as e:
        return e

def det2(M):
    #to find determinant of 2x2 matrix
    # T(n) = O(1)
    try:
        one = M[0][0] * M[1][1]
        two = M[0][1] * M[1][0]

        return (one-two)
    except Exception as e:
        return e

def det3(M):
    #to find determinant of 3x3 matrix
    #T(n) = O(3*N^2) = O(n^2)
    try:
        one = M[0][0] * cofactor(M,0,0)
        two = M[0][1] * cofactor(M,0,1)
        three = M[0][2] * cofactor(M,0,2)

        return one+two+three
    except Exception as e:
        return e

def rank(M):
    #to find rank of matrix
    #M must be 3*3
    """
    T(n) = t1 + t2
    t1(n) = O(n^2) + o(1) == O(N^2)
    t2(n) = n*n*O(n**2) == n^4
    T(n) = O(n^4)
    """

    d1 = det3(M)
    if d1 != 0: 
        return len(M) #O(1)
    elif d1 == 0:
        last = 0
        for i in range(len(M)): #n
            for j in range(len(M)): #n
                m = minor(M,i,j) # T(N) = O(N^2)
                d = det2(m) # O(1)
                if d != 0:
                    return len(m) # O(1)
                else:
                   if M[i][j] != 0:
                      last = [[1]]
    return len(last)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    matrix = [[0,0,0],
              [0,0,0],
              [0,1,1]]

    print(rank(matrix))
```

Comment: What exactly is `n` if your matrices are always 3x3?

Comment: n: size of array, actually this code is limited to only 3*3 matrix

Comment: Yes, your calculation is correct because usage of 'minor' complexity is necessary.